# Text Analysis to determine Offer Performance

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, analytics, predictive

I'm currently exploring different ways to judge and predict the performance of various offers and marketing campaigns. I have a list of metrics to pull from which I'm currently using now to predict performance, such as:

- Day the offer was sent
- Month
- Weather
- Time of Day
- +more

And for my performance metric, I use

- Redemption Rate (For every offer sent, how many times was it redeemed) - This is how I judge success

But one of the most important metrics is the offer itself, which I know in the form of a text-string.

Here are a few user-generated examples.

- Get $4.00 off a large pizza
- Receive 20% off your next order
- Buy any Chocolate Milkshake, get another one half price
- Two wraps for $7.50
- Free cookie with any purchase

..and hundred's more

Now, I know there's very important information in those text stings, but I don't know the best way to analyze it and extract key information. For example, in this text it shows the product its advertising, the discount, the dollar amount, the percentage off, etc. I need a generalized way to go through each string (I'm assuming through some tolkenized method), and extract relevant information.

I'm hoping to get some input on how I could analyze these strings, eventually with the purpose of generating a string-based dataset (along with the other aforementioned data points) that I can use for predictions.

I am writing my code using python 3.0.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please be more concrete: what information do you want to extract from these strings, how do you want to organize your data? Which attempts have you already made? And how did they fail? Please provide [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you want feedback on.

Comment: The issue isn't the code, and I wanted to avoid posting it here. Its a generic randromforest algorithim using 1's and 0's to determine if an offer was sent on a particular day, month, etc. What I want to try and do is see if the way the offers are phrased affects the performance of the offer, but I don't really know how to start. It's a fairly opened ended question, but I just was hoping for some direction on a good place to start looking. It might not be possible, but if someone had ever done something similar, i'd love to see methods as to how they did it. Thanks.